# What are the purpose of the six hunting styles?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations-ultimate

There are six ‘hunting styles’. They are as follows:

- Guild
- Striker
- Aerial
- Alchemy
- Brave
- Adept

What’s the point in choosing one style over the other? What is each one supposed to do for you? Is one maybe meant to assist you to become a tank, or a support class, for example?

Comment: What the heck? Why was this put off as unreleased when the eastern version has been out for mor then a year! I ask that this be removed from being on hold!

Comment: Yeah, its been out for a while. Which means this info should be readily available. What research have you done on your own?

Comment: @Frank because frank, i fortunately I have a hard time reading the reddit posts and articles in japanese

Comment: I sincerely doubt that's all there is available.  I myself have read some articles about this.  In English.

Comment: @Frank couldn’t Any question on this site be answered through enough research? I don’t have the time do it, and I still want someone to reopen my question

Comment: Yes, just about any question could.  But the point I'm making is that *you* should be doing it, as it's *your* question.  If you don't have the time to do it, why should you expect others to do your work for you?  I personally wouldn't have voted to close your question, but I sure downvoted it for lack of research.  I question the utility of asking it, in the first place; I don't see what's useful about this at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78152/discussion-between-hobo-warrior-and-frank).

Comment: actually, there is only 2 new styles, Alchemy and Brave. Generations/X had the same 4, and they all determine your playstyle. Much like anything else Monster Hunter, there is little "point" in choosing one over the other, except that X style works for you.

Comment: I can list what each style does(though this is extremely easily wiki'd), but a "best" style will definitely be closed as opinion

Comment: @Rapitor could you do that for me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, Firstly. There are only 2 new styles to Generations Ultimate/XX. Those being Brave and Alchemy. I will still run down the four original styles as well, though:

**Guild**: Traditional hunting, there's really nothing special about this style, it feels most familiar to monster hunter veterans. All-Rounder. 2 art slots

**Striker**: Artful Hunting, This style excels at building your hunter arts, letting you use them more often. Offensive. 3 art slots

**Aerial**: Aerial Hunting, This style replaces most weapon's dodge with a hop. allowing you to land aerial attacks more often and get mounting done. Offensive. 1 art slot

**Adept**: Defensive hunting, This style strengthens dodges and blocks, giving counterattack abilities, and makes living easier. Defensive. 1 art slot

**Alchemy(new)**: Supportive Hunting, You are given a special barrel item that produces unique items and effects that recharges. Supportive. 3 art slots

**Brave(new)**: Offensive Hunting, Heavily altered movesets for all weapons, Parry ability used to charge the brave gauge for unique moves. Offensive. 1 art slot

All styles alter weapons slightly in some way, (like the gunlance can't shell midair while using adept style, for example. I don't think this is the exact case, this is just an example.)